# cscope E257: cstag: tag not found

Tags: vimrc, cscope

I try to compile `vim` with `cscope`. However, I keep encountering the error `E257: cstag: tag not found`, no matter what position the cursor locates at when pressing `CTRL ]`.

My vim version is `8.2`. My dir structure is

```
root 
|---src 
     |---a.c 
     |---b.c 
     |---c.c
```

I have done the following :

1. stick the file `cscope_maps.vim` in my $HOME/.vim/plugin
2. in the project `root`, use `cscope -R` to generate database.

However, even though the cscope GUI works fine after `cscope -R` and I could see the file `cscope.out` in the root directory, I could not jump to the definition with `CTRL ]`, which shows the error `E257: cstag: tag not found`

Comment: `:help cscope-how-touse`: perhaps you need `:cs add cscope.out`? Check `:cs show`

Comment: wow thanks @D.BenKnoble. Could you formalize your comment as an answer ? Like why we need `:cs add cscope.out` and how it is not automatically compiled ?